# Change the timezone for SliceStart\SliceEnd in Azure data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

When using an Azure Data Factory copy activity, I can fire a source SQL Query such as

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ModifiedTime BETWEEN SliceStart and SliceEnd
```

However SliceStart and SliceEnd seem to be in UTC. How would I convert them to another timezone, specifically a timezone affected by DST such as PST assuming I cannot deploy code on the source database.

Comment: have you tried converting the time in the query using any sql server date conversion method?

Comment: @Nava As far  as I know, SQL Server does not have a native method where you can covert between timezones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using one of the time manipulation function of data factory as a workaround for this issue [ADF Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution/#data-factory-functions-reference)

```
{
"Type": "SqlSource",
"sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE StartTime = \\'{0:yyyyMMdd-HH}\\'', WindowStart)"
}
```

it's not a PST conversion, but you can use it as a workaround.

There's no way to do this via ADF functions, you should create a function or stored procedure in SQL Server and call it from the sqlReaderQuery defined in the pipeline. 
But, since you can not change the source database, seems that this can not be achieved using Data Factory...

Comment: Thanks Nava  , I'm aware of those functions, and they would work absolutely fine with most timezones. However, certain timezones are affected by DST which means that they change, in some months they can be UTC -8, in some months UTC-7 . Normal date manipulation functions dont work for such timezones

Comment: just looked at the programmatic approach for creating pipelines [programmatic ADF](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-create-data-factories-programmatically/). this might to the trick

Comment: Since there's no way to do this via ADF functions, you should create a fucntion or stored procedure in SQL Server and call it fro, the sqlReaderQuery defined in the pipline

Comment: the initial question mentioned 'assuming I cannot deploy code on the source database.' --  However, could you add your comment to the answer and I'll go ahead and accept it? since this specifically seems to be unsupported in ADF natively

Comment: I now see that I have missed that part. updated my original answer.

Comment: @NavaVaismanLevy Hi, I am having the same issue, I want to change the UTC timezone to AEST. But I don't understand your answer, where should I make that change?

Comment: @NavaVaismanLevy I know that I can use Dateadd(hour, x, \\'{0:yyyyMMdd-HH}\\'), but in that case, I will have to modify all the pipelines. I am looking for a way to update the whole pipeline